# How to check asset bundle's target platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, build-target

I have a database which contains asset bundles for my game which are built for both android and ios.

Sometimes, i mistakenly put ios asset bundle into android database or vice versa. I want to get notified in Unity if i make this mistake.

Is it possible to check Asset Bundle's target platform after downloading it?